# How to make a firefox addon that acts as an offline website

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

What I want to do is that when the user clicks a button I will add to firefox (or clicks an option I will add under tools, etc), a new tab should be opened, and in the tab will essentially be an offline website that is written in HTML/CSS/JS and will be part of the addon.

How can I do this? It does not matter to me if I require a very new version of firefox to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Making your first firefox addon can be quite challenging, at first. But once you make one, things get much better. Here are some tools to help you get started:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/tools/builder

I suggest you start with this and check all the features. Once you download the skeleton, look over ff-overlay.xul in the /chrome/content folder. It should be straightforward if you know XUL/Javascript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Setting_up_extension_development_environment

This link helps you set up Firefox for easy addon testing and debugging.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser

The Mozilla Developer Network is incredibly useful. For example, that link takes you to a page that explains everything about switching tabs.

https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/

Addon playground.

Remember, Google's your friend! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. So I tried `gBrowser.selectedTab = gBrowser.addTab("http://www.myremoteserver.com/index.html");` and that worked fine. Any idea how to do `gBrowser.selectedTab = gBrowser.addTab("./fileInMyAddonDirectory.html");`?

Comment: It turns out if I use `chrome://extensionname/content/fileInMyContentDirectory.html` it works. Thanks again for your help :)